# Permutation and combination with path?

Tags: c#, .net

I have input is like "dir1/dir2/Demo.txt"

with combination I want output like

- "dir1/dir2/Demo.txt"
- "dir1/dir2/DEMO.txt"
- "dir1/DIR2/Demo.txt"
- "dir1/DIR2/DEMO.txt"
- "DIR1/dir2/Demo.txt"
- "DIR1/dir2/DEMO.txt"
- "DIR1/DIR2/Demo.txt"
- "DIR1/DIR2/DEMO.txt"

as per my knowledge I written code as below

```
   var s = "dir1/dir2/Demo.txt";
   List<string> listPermutations = new List<string>();
   string[] array = s.Split('/');
   int iterations = (1 << array.Length) -1;
   for( int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++ )
   {
       for( int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++ )
            array[j] = (i & (1<<j)) != 0
                ? array[j].ToUpper()
                : array[j];
       listPermutations.Add(string.Join("/",array ));
   }
```

Comment: So what is your problem ?

Comment: The problem is I can't able to produce output as per I given in demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you keep overwriting your "source" array, use temporary array instead for each individual permutation:

```
        var s = "dir1/dir2/Demo.txt";
        List<string> listPermutations = new List<string>();
        string[] array = s.Split('/');
        int iterations = (1 << array.Length) - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
        {
            var tmp = new string[array.Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                tmp [j] = (i & (1 << j)) != 0
                     ? array[j].ToUpper()
                     : array[j];
            listPermutations.Add(string.Join("/", tmp));
        }
```

Output (if simply iterating over `listPermutations`):

```
dir1/dir2/Demo.txt
DIR1/dir2/Demo.txt
dir1/DIR2/Demo.txt
DIR1/DIR2/Demo.txt
dir1/dir2/DEMO.TXT
DIR1/dir2/DEMO.TXT
dir1/DIR2/DEMO.TXT
DIR1/DIR2/DEMO.TXT
```

I tried a "minimal fix" for your given code, that has the following results:

- The extension (`.TXT`) will also be uppercased (because it is part of the last component if split by `\` alone).
- The order of results is different than what you have proposed.
- The resulting code could be more efficient/clear.

You will have to deal with that if required.